# update in realtime using - jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, real-time, real-time-updates

using ASP.NET I use a repeater to displaying a DB table on screen.

I want the user to be able to check or uncheck a tick box(field in the table).  Updating the corresponding field in the DB in Management Studio on real time.....

Looking through google. JQuery seems the way....so far I have got...

in code behind:

```
//GetUtilityCompanyNames() returns a list of all the companies names
 rptSelectedUtilities.DataSource = GetUtilityCompanyNames();
 rptSelectedUtilities.DataBind();
```

In aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptSelectedUtilities" runat="server" DataSourceID="rptSelectedUtilities">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
                        <tr>   
                            <th style="width:200px;">Utility</th>    
                            <th style="width:200px;">Contacted</th>   
                            <th style="width:200px;">Comment</th>    
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Name") %></th>
                            <th style="width:200px;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyCheck" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>'/></th>   
                            <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Comment") %></th>  
                        </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

            <asp:Label id="labelTableEmpty" runat="server" Text="There are currently no items in this table." />

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('bla').
```

//dont kno how to start here??

I've set the DataSourceID on the repeater to="rptSelectedUtilities", then i need to add in the Script but I am a beginner at this and would appreciate any help please.

Thanks

Comment: You may be in for a big learning curve here. What you're essentially asking is "how do I use AJAX in ASP.NET?" which is very, very broad. At a high level, you need to create server-side handlers to update your data and you need to call those handlers from JavaScript code. Understand that there is a hard separation between the server-side code and the client-side code. While you've used a data source and a repeater to bind the initial page load, once loaded you can completely forget about those things. Now you're dealing with the HTML DOM, JavaScript, and RESTful requests/responses.

Comment: Ok well thanks for that david but i've been wanting to give something like this a go for a while now and I thought this would be the perfect opportunity to implement this into my project. I assumed this wouldnt be too difficult if I got some sort of minor help with it to get me started, It doesnt seem like that big of a task, a check box which updates the Db when clicked or unclicked, but as I say Im a beginner this could be very complex for all I know...thanks anyway

Comment: I encourage you to do so. Web development becomes a lot more capable when one learns the underlying technologies more effectively (HTTP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.). I'm having trouble coming up with a single answer which can really get you going, though. Keeping that separation between server-side and client-side foremost in your mind is key, though. Think of the in-browser code as an entirely separate application from the server-side code. It treats the server-side code as a web service. So you create your web (JSON, in this case) services in ASP.NET and consume them in JavaScript.

Comment: @John, what are you using in your code behind? VB, C#?

Comment: OK sounds good...Think I get the overall mind set of what needs to be done - the hard part now is getting started I'll just keep googling and hopefully hit something of reference...cheers

Comment: @JackPettinger im' using c#, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are really needing this to be realtime I would suggest looking at [signalr](http://signalr.net/). It might be a lot to bite off this early in your learning stage but I am currently switching out all of my ajax calls to use signalr instead.

Comment: This man is right, please take the time to look at SignalR, it's very good for realtime web applications.